# Which characters, canonically, can stop Mjölnir in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, mjolnir

In *Thor: Ragnarok* (2017), Hela is able to destroy Thor's hammer. However, she is first able to stop the hammer when it is thrown. **Are there other characters who are able to stop - but not necessarily wield - Mjölnir?**

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly we've only seen Hela be able to override the worthiness enchantment which is why Thor and Loki are so surprised. How she does it (raw power, was hers before?) is up for debate. So canonically that would only be Hela. Are you asking us if others could do the same and so guess which in turn wouldn't be canonical.

Comment: What about Thanos? I thought I remembered him stopping it

Comment: @PeterNielsen actually Thanos did not stop it, he only deflected Mjölnir, and used Thor's attraction of Stormbreaker to push it in his chest. He is not worthy, so he cannot wield any of those two.

Comment: I've made a mistake in my last comment, you don't need to be worthy to wield Stormbreaker.

Comment: Vision and Captain America wielded it, so presumably they might also be able to stop it, assuming they remained worthy? Doing so might rely on regular strength rather than anything magical, so I'd bet on Vision if I had to.